# measuring code perfomance of queries, what to think of the result?

Tags: c#

I have some code that looks like this:

```
    public void SomeMethodThatLoadsUserData()
    {
       Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
       sw.Start();

       Parallel.Invoke(Method1, Method2, .... , Method12);

       sw.Stop();
       var t = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}
```

Each of these methods end up calling a query in the database. When I hit the Debug button, the first time this code runs it takes about 1200ms. And then, when I hit the restart button, after about 10 times, the result averages around 220ms.

**Is this huge gap due to the fact that A**) the first time the application must do some sort of compilation and the actual result on a production environment will be closer to the 220ms average I'm getting on my laptop **or B**) the data is cached in SQL server and when I hit the restart the data is read from cache and therefore the real performance of the method on a production environment will actually be closer to the 1200ms I see on the first run.

Thanks for your suggestion on how to read these figures.

Comment: you're right about SQL caching the query & results, so that's a major time savings. If you're curious about the query performance you can dig into the timings with SqlServer Profiler.

Comment: You are profiling a *ton* of code you didn't write and cannot change.  Only consider doing anything at all if you stop your program, start it back up and it again takes 1200 msec.  Then use a profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to caching, depending on how you query your db (orm may cache, DB does caching, ..). There are a few things you have to consider:

- Running this method only once does say nothing, run it a few hundred times and take the avg. So you can eliminate startup time, cold caches and whatever the .NET runtime has to load at runtime.
- Mock the database to see if any caching occurs on DB side or if latency has an impact
- For many DBs there are tools which help in optimizing SQL Queries especially for the DB you're using. If you want to benchmark the query, use these.
- Run benchmarks with release builds as they may be more optimized